# Where can I get information on the number of iOS devices sold and on iOS activations?

Tags: ios

Where can I get a table with the number of iOS devices sold worldwide, specifically for:

- iPhone (first generation)
- iPhone 3G
- iPhone 3GS
- iPhone 4
- iPad
- iPad 2
- the iPod series

And the number of iOS activations for:

- iOS 4.3
- iOS 4.2
- iPhone 3.1.3
- iPhone 3.1.2

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can. That sort of information tends to be confidential within companies. Apple occasionally talks about general numbers (they sold eleventy billion iPads in the first month) and you can attempt to extrapolate from there.

There are also third-party sources that have revealed their own related statistics, but those will be incomplete and possibly inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

Horace Dedieu at asymco.com is one of the most accurate and perceptive analysts out there and has assembled a wealth of detail to examine.

Comment: And speaking of him, there is VERY interesting news coming from the Apple lawsuit against Samsung. [link] (http://www.asymco.com/2011/04/19/review-of-apples-unit-numbers-released-in-legal-filing-prior-to-earnings/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with CajunLake, but some quick searches will reveal the numbers Apple *has* disclosed.  For example, [see this](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/01/18/apple_has_sold_160m_ios_devices_average_iphone_price_grows_to_625.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking around sites like the Wall Street Journal? I think they normally get that stuff. You can also try digging around investor relations... http://phx.corporate-ir.net/phoenix.zhtml?c=107357&p=irol-reports I don't think they'll break it down enough for any real answers, but if you find apple's profit per phone/items; you can do the math.

Answer (score 0):

The best places to find out numbers are earnings calls and keynotes. Other than that, it's tight lipped.